# Java - Asnyc wait?

Tags: java, minecraft

So I'm coding a Minecraft Client in JAVA and in a ,,Spammer'' module, I need to wait between messages. So this is my question, how? If I do `Thread.sleep()` or `TimeUnit.MILLISECOND.wait()`, it freezes the client while it's sending the messages.

Comment: Look into Bukkit's Scheduler `scheduleSyncRepeatingTask`

Comment: I'm not creating a plugin but a client - using mcp. I can't use Bukkit stuff here :(

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to use this class `java.util.concurrent.Future`. This one is intended to deal with async stuff. Check this article https://www.baeldung.com/java-future

Comment: How exactly would I use Future here? I mean I tried `public Future saymsg  = mc.thePlayer.sendChatMessage(message);` but it errors because it is a void

Comment: No, but I can upload it if you need